# Solr Hierarchical Faceting. Example needed

Tags: solr

I am new to solr. I want to implement hierarchical faceting in my application. I went through 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting and also for the preparation of correct xml.

My need is to push XML to solr for indexing and it should show expected results as shown in solr wiki.

Problem:
I am not understanding how should I specify facet fields in solrconfig/schema and also in the xml that will be posted. IF anyone  out there can provide me example configuration that will be great. I would like to do it as it is performing on solr hierarchical wiki above.

I may be sounding like a total newbie here but I am stuck .

Ref Document-

```
<add>
  <doc> 
    <field name="id">4</field> 
    <field name="0/NonFic">General</field> 
    <field name="1/NonFic/Law">Rules</field> 
    <field name="1/NonFic/Sci">Chemistry</field> 
    <field name="1/NonFic/Sci">Physics</field> 
  </doc> 
</add>
```

Thanks
89neuron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in configuration for [Solr Pivots](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets) and they don't need special configuration.

With the XML data configure as a simple field or multivalued field separate field.

Configure the fields as is in string format multivalued fields, if needed.
For e.g. field for Country and state would be 2 different fields.

Only during Search, you would need to pass `facet.pivot=country,state` to get the Hierarchy Facets.

```
<add>
  <doc> 
    <field name="id">4</field> 
    <field name="country">US</field> 
    <field name="country">India</field> 
    <field name="state">mumbai</field> 
    <field name="state">Nevada</field> 
  </doc> 
</add>
```

Comment: Could you pelase check if my document data is correct ?<add>
<doc>
<field name="id">4</field>
  <field name="0/NonFic">General</field>
<field name="1/NonFic/Law">Rules</field>
<field name="1/NonFic/Sci">Chemistry</field>
<field name="1/NonFic/Sci">Physics</field>
</doc>
</add>

Comment: you need not have the data to change now. added example.

Comment: I wanted to have something like-http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#A.27facet.prefix.27__Based_Drill_Down

Comment: Thanks a lot Jayendra. I also posted my document which Srikanth has edited above to solr and also made some configurations in schema to recognize 0/NonFic and others. Facet Pivot and Field queries seem to be working now. Will work more on it and come back. Are we sure we do not need to make any configurations in solrconfig to tell prefix?